# Get list of all matching modules on Python import path

Tags: python-import, python-packaging, python-importlib

When I do `import foo` Python will go through the Python path (`sys.path`) looking for a match, and import the first match.

But there might be more than one path that has a matching module. Is there a way of getting a list of all the matching modules?

Also, I need a method that does not actually import the package since the package may be broken such that attempting to import it results in a fatal error.

The following works even though `foo` is broken:

```
pkgloader = pkgutil.find_loader('foo')
print(pkgloader.get_filename())
```

But I need something that finds all matching modules, e.g. `pkgutil.find_all_loaders('foo')`.